# Local median and local average

Tags: mean, image-processing

I have two pictures representing two laboratory experiments. The idea is that every black band represent one sample. Now I need to use special application to measure the bands intensity, which tell me how much product from reaction I have. For every picture I can do 'background subtraction' which will give me more reliable answer.

I have the option: 'local median' and 'local average' subtraction. Which one will be better for every of them? and why?

[image]
[image]

Comment: It depends on how you identify "background." If it is to be automatically identified from parts of the same image that are believed to be in non-sample areas, then please see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/100484/background-subtraction-for-signal-and-error-analysis for a discussion.  If it is identified from a similar image taken with the sample absent, then a different answer might apply.